# R studio doesn't start up correctly even after reinstallation

Tags: r, windows, rstudio

I am running R studio on windows, it was working fine, until recently my PC had an issue with the bluetooth driver and forced a system restore. Now, it seems all the R studio packages are missing and whenever i launch it, i get this error

```
 Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) : 
  DLL 'jsonlite' not found: maybe not installed for this architecture?
Calls: do.call ... namespaceImportFrom -> asNamespace -> loadNamespace -> library.dynam
Execution halted
```

I will then install the package **jsonlite** in this case, only to restart R studio and be greeted with a similar error but for another package.
My R studio version: `RStudio 2023.03.1+446 "Cherry Blossom" Release (6e31ffc3ef2a1f81d377eeccab71ddc11cfbd29e, 2023-05-09) for windows`

I have tried uninstalling R studio with iobit uninstaller, and even installing a newer version, but it gives the same issues.
I cant load any library with the library() function as i get an error of a missing dependency or something, it seems i'll have to keep installing every missing package, but i do not have enough time to get that done.

This is the error i encountered when i tried to load tidyr:

```
library(tidyr)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyr’ in runHook(".onLoad", env, package.lib, package):
 cannot open file 'C:/Users/CryptoKellz/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2/lifecycle/R/lifecycle.rdb': No such file or directory
```

Comment: It's probably best if you just delete your personal library folder all together. If you delete "C:/Users/CryptoKellz/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2" that should delete all installed packages. Then when you re-install a package, it should install all it's dependencies.

Comment: should i uninstall r studio first or just delete the folder before uninstalling?

Comment: Just delete the folder. No need to uninstall RStudio. Just make sure it's not running when you delete the folder to be extra careful.